# Как реализовать подобный эффект текста?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css3

Увидел на сайте [www.amandabraga.com](http://www.amandabraga.com) при скроле интересный эффект текста. Текст/изображение которое ближе к нижней границе браузера при скроле искажается и встает на место. Попробовал сделать что то подобное на blotter.js но не получилось. Подскажите, как реализовать такой эффект?

Comment: Пример вашего кода? Пишет какие-то ошибки?

Comment: @Quazimorda, а как ожидать код, если человек не понимает вообще как устроен эффект?

Comment: мб у меня комп динозавр, но тупит это жутко

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень похоже на эффект перспективы

[https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/#:~:text=The%20perspective%20CSS%20property%20gives,more%20impressive%20the%20visual%20effect](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/#:%7E:text=The%20perspective%20CSS%20property%20gives,more%20impressive%20the%20visual%20effect).

https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/perspective

https://html5book.ru/3d-transform/

Хотя залез в код сайта (через консоль разработчика - F12)

Внизу сайта есть невидимый блок высотой с эффект, скрытый. Аналогично есть блок сверху, тоже скрытый.

Когда пользователь скролит, то эти блоки становятся видимыми (в зависимости от направления скрола)

У них появляется css-стиль `translate3d` и `rotateX`, которые меняются со временем (задана анимация тоже через css-стиль)